# Object with nested array into array

Tags: typescript

I have an object, in it there's an array of ojects:

```
const data = [
  {
    role: "admin",
    users: [
      {
        name: "john",
        user_id: "1234",
      },
      {
        name: "Peter",
        user_id: "4321",
      },
    ],
  },
];
console.log(data);
```

How do transform this to get an array like below?

```
0: {role: "admin", name: "john", user_id: "1234"  }
1: {role: "admin", name: "Peter", user_id: "4321"  }
```

Comment: Does `data.flatMap(v => v.users.map(u => ({ role: v.role, ...u })))` meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer (but I'm sure there's probably a dupe target somewhere). If not what am I missing?

Comment: Hi there. No, role must be on the same level as name and user_id

Comment: [Have you actually tried it](https://tsplay.dev/NlMRem)?  Looks like it works to me.  If you have a problem with the code could you explain exactly the difference between what my suggestion produces and what you want?  Preferably via a code example and not just verbally?

Comment: Your code generates this: [ { role: 'admin',
    users: 
     [ { name: 'john', user_id: '1234' },
       { name: 'Peter', user_id: '4321' } ] } ]
This is the expected:
[ { role: 'admin',
    name: 'john',
    user_id: '1234' },
  { role:'admin',
    name: 'Peter',
    user_id: '4321' } ]

Comment:  No, it absolutely does not generate that output.  As proof, please [look at this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NVlJ7W), and run the code there, and observe the output. At least one of us is terribly confused here.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're correct. I was having a problem with Quokka.js extension not showing me the correct value. Thank you so much!